# How can I send a post request to another API from my own application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create_item/', CreateItem.as_view()),
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ParentReferans(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.IntegerField()
class ItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    SubItem = serializers.BooleanField()
    Type = serializers.CharField()
    Name = serializers.CharField()
    ParentRef = ParentReferans(many=True, read_only=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateItem(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        response = requests.post('https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/4620816365135062310/item?minorversion=4', data=request.data)

        serializer = ItemSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to send post request to (https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/4620816365135062310/item?minorversion=4) address. But I could not come to a conclusion about what I could do. How should I go about this problem?

Comment: The `requests` python module is excellent for this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't know how to respond.

Comment: Silly me -- I didn't see that you're already using it!

Comment: So you're already using `requests.post()`.  What is your specific question?  Are you asking what input you should provide to the post?

Comment: I'm asking how to return. Because when I return, I get a status error.

Comment: So I am confused about what to return. There is a serializer and response.

Comment: You're never using the `response` object that is returned from the post, so I'm really confused as to what your question is.

Comment: I think we have a language barrier here.  I can't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: OK. I want one thing. I want to send a request to the address I have specified above. How can I do this in the view?

Comment: You're already doing that, with the `requests.post(...)` line.

Comment: I get error: name 'status' is not defined. My new post code : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HtnYnKBHWr/

Comment: And this is exactly why I am confused.  You said you wanted "one thing", to send a request to the address, but you keep bringing up errors that have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = requests.post(url,params={"paramName": "paramValue"})
```